# Gitlab-ci-multi-runner continues if npm publish fails

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, npm-publish

I use gitlab-ci-multi-runner to publish our artifact to our own npm registry. This is the .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
publish-continuous:
  type: publish
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run test
    - npm run build
    - npm publish --registry $env:NPM_REGISTRY_URL
```

Sometimes the npm publish fails. This is the output:

```
$ npm publish --registry $env:NPM_REGISTRY_URL
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\SomeUser\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "publish" "--registry" "https://ourownregistry"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.6.0
npm ERR! code ENEEDAUTH
```

I would expect that the gitlab-ci-multi-runner stops because the job fails. But it doesn't! It reports **Build succeeded.**

Anyone knows how I can make the build fail if npm publish fails?

Comment: Hmm, maybe npm publish returns 0 although it throws an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by updating to the latest NPM. v3.8.1 fixed the issue. Now it returns a -1 exit code and the build fails.